# Delete AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application Versions up to certain date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

In the AWS documentation, it is described how to delete Elastic Beanstalk application versions [via the frontend](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-versions.html) and [via the EB CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/delete-application-version.html). 
However, in the frontend one has to check each application version to be deleted. In the EB CLI one has to call the delete command for every application version to be deleted.

Is there an easier way to delete all application versions up to a certain date?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://www.danmandle.com/blog/automatically-remove-old-aws-elastic-beanstalk-application-versions/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the AWS CLI or one of the AWS SDKs.  You can write a script to:

1. Describe the Application Versions [CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/describe-application-versions.html) [Node.js](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ElasticBeanstalk.html#describeApplicationVersions-property)
2. Loop over them with the delete. [CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/delete-application-version.html) [Node.js](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ElasticBeanstalk.html#deleteApplicationVersion-property)

There are other [lanuages](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) to choose from as well.